# Javaweb service on https sslexception unexpected_message

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, https

I'm developing an application that use a webservice on https when I call the method of the webservice i get this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:208)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)...
```

I have been looking for a solution but nothing works, i have experience on web services but nothing on https, it also has a usernametoken for authentication but that's later

I call the method like this

```
.getmessage(message);
```

i'm using web service client on netbeans, i never had problems with regular web services and i'm kind of new on this and i'm a little confused i need some orientation to go to through the right way

Comment: Please run your client with the command-line argument -Djavax.net.debug=SSL,handshake and post the results here. Edit them into your question. You may also have to do the same thing at the server, or get hold of its SSL logs if it isn't a Java server.

Comment: i dont have access to the server but it is a java server, i will try your solution thks i will post the result

Comment: It's not a 'solution', it's a debugging suggestion. You might have to get access to the server. There is a problem to be solved.